# R equivalents of xtcointtest and xtpmg

Tags: r, stata

I am trying to find R equivalents of two Stata (14.2) commands: `xtcointtest` and `xtpmg`.

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a `xtpmg` R equivalent you could try [pmg](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plm/versions/2.6-1/topics/pmg).